# PHP prepared statement always returns 1

Tags: php, mysql, prepared-statement

I tryed to call a function from a prepared Statement

```
stmt= $conn->prepare("SELECT create_user(?,?,?)");
$tt="test";
$stmt->bind_param("sss",$tt,$tt,$tt);
$stmt->execute();
echo "RETURN VALUE".$stmt->fetch();
```

the returnvalue shouldn't be 1
the function is working if i call it that way directly in mysql console
the function is working correctly and is also applying the changes but the return value is allways 1 no matter what it's returning on the console
I tried to execute another Statement to check if there is a mistake in my function
there are 4 rows in the table

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT Count(Name) from users");
$stmt->execute();
echo $stmt->fetch();
```

the result is the (it's 1 again) same if i do
    `$stmt->store_result();`
before fetching the result
I'm working with mySQL DB

Comment: `mysqli_stmt::fetch`, which I assume you're referring to here, has three possible return values: `true`, `false` and `null`. It does not actually return the data from the database. Please consult the manual for how to use the mysqli API to get data from the database.

Comment: ^@deceze is right, I had my PDO & MySQLi mixed up...

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-result.php

Comment: A downvote seems a little harsh. Yes there is enough info in the docs to figure this one out, but we all miss something at one time or another. I personally think it's completely counter-intuitive for a function called `fetch()` not to return the data it's fetched, so this would be an easy mistake to make.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have to try something like this:

```
$stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT Count(Name) as count from users");
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($count);
$stmt->fetch();
echo $count
```